# What am I doing wrong here? The count is being stored and transferred to the other group of buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I have been struggling with this, please can you help? Here is the code. I want the group buttons to work independently from each other. F.example, if I press the Home buttons, the count should not transfer to the Guest button. It should begin from zero when clicked, but it counts what has been stored in the variable prior to it being clicked.

```js
const homeScreen = document.getElementById("home-screen");
const guestScreen = document.getElementById("guest-screen");
let count = 0;

homeScreen.textContent = 0;
guestScreen.textContent = 0;

const plusOne = () => {
  count += 1;
  
    guestScreen.textContent = count;
  
}

const plusTwo = () => {
  count += 2;
  guestScreen.textContent = count;
}

const plusThree = () => {
  count += 3;
  let result = guestScreen.textContent = count;
  if (result.length !== 0) {
    return result;
  }
}

const reset = () => {
  guestScreen.textContent = 0;
}

const homeOne = () => {
  count += 1;
  homeScreen.textContent = count;
  
  console.log("Clicked Home");
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between bd-highlight mb-2">
      <div id="left">
        <h3 class="home">HOME</h3>
        <span id="home-screen" class="float-start rounded"></span>
        <div>
        <button onclick="homeOne()" class="btn btn-info">+1</button>
          <button onclick="homeTwo()" class="btn btn-info">+1</button>
          <button onclick="homeThree()" class="btn btn-info">+1</button>
          </div>
      </div>
    <div><Button onclick="reset()" class="btn reset">Reset</Button> </div>
      <div id="left">
        <h3 class="text">GUEST</h3>
    <span id="guest-screen" class="float-end rounded"></span>
        <div>
          <button onclick="plusOne()" class="btn ">+1</button>
          <button onclick="plusTwo()" class="btn ">+1</button>
          <button onclick="plusThree()" class="btn ">+1</button>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row">
      
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-5">
        </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then use two different variable: `homeCount`  and `guestCount` .

```js
const homeScreen = document.getElementById("home-screen");
const guestScreen = document.getElementById("guest-screen");
let homeCount = 0;
let guestCount = 0;

homeScreen.textContent = 0;
guestScreen.textContent = 0;

const plusOne = () => {
  guestCount += 1;
  guestScreen.textContent = guestCount;
}

const plusTwo = () => {
  guestCount += 2;
  guestScreen.textContent = guestCount;
}

const plusThree = () => {
  guestCount += 3;
  guestScreen.textContent = guestCount;
  
  // Unclear what was attempted here...
  // let result = guestScreen.textContent = guestCount;
  // if (result.length !== 0) {
  //   return result;
  // }
}

const reset = () => {
  guestScreen.textContent = 0;
}

const homeOne = () => {
  homeCount += 1;
  homeScreen.textContent = homeCount;
}

const homeTwo = () => {
  homeCount += 2;
  homeScreen.textContent = homeCount;
}

const homeThree = () => {
  homeCount += 3;
  homeScreen.textContent = homeCount;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between bd-highlight mb-2">
      <div id="left">
        <h3 class="home">HOME</h3>
        <span id="home-screen" class="float-start rounded"></span>
        <div>
        <button onclick="homeOne()" class="btn btn-info">+1</button>
          <button onclick="homeTwo()" class="btn btn-info">+2</button>
          <button onclick="homeThree()" class="btn btn-info">+3</button>
          </div>
      </div>
    <div><Button onclick="reset()" class="btn reset">Reset</Button> </div>
      <div id="left">
        <h3 class="text">GUEST</h3>
    <span id="guest-screen" class="float-end rounded"></span>
        <div>
          <button onclick="plusOne()" class="btn ">+1</button>
          <button onclick="plusTwo()" class="btn ">+2</button>
          <button onclick="plusThree()" class="btn ">+3</button>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row">
      
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-5">
        </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Lol, this is why you need an extra head to think the simple thing it cannot comprehend. Thank you, that actually solves my issue. I was thinking too complicated a thought and missed the simple trick right there. Thanks again, means alot.

Comment: Great! Then can you mark my answer as accepted (green check mark)?